# CPUIdle: what could be the reason for a core refusing entering the C6 state though the kernel requests so?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm trying to measure the time that a core spent in each c-state during a workload run and found a weird phenomenon: the kernel requests a core to enter C6, but the hardware only stays in C1.

The workload runs on 4 cores: cpu 2-5, and I use turbostat to obtain the c-states statistics of them. Below is the data in a 1-second measurement interval:

```
| CPU  | C1% | C1E% | C6%   | CPU%c1 | CPU%c6 |
| :---:|:---:|:---:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
|    2 |1.57 | 0.00|  78.98 | 74.22  |  6.09  |
|    3 |1.80 | 0.00|  78.80 | 74.64  |  5.72  |
|    4 |2.07 | 0.00|  78.66 | 74.02  |  6.48  |
|    5 |1.69 | 0.00|  78.87 | 74.80  |  5.53  |
```

While the kernel asked the core to enter C6 almost 80% during this interval, the hardware actually only spent 6% of the time in C6 and stayed in C1 mainly. This table only contains the statistics in 1 second, but it's pretty much what happened during the entire workload run (about 40 seconds). What could be the reason for the hardware refusing the kernel's request of entering C6 and instead entering C1?

Below is some information about the server on which the above experiment ran:

```
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8280M CPU @ 2.70GHz

Thread(s) per core: 1

Kernel version: 5.15.0-69-generic

CPUidle driver: intel_idle

CPUidle governor: menu

Enabled idle states: POLL, C1, C6 (C1E is disabled)
```